# How do I stop my javascript timer from resetting?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a countdown timer here

When it reaches 0:00 i would like it to end here and just show 0:00. But it resets again at 2 minutes

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var twoMinutes = 60 * 2,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(twoMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<span id="time">2:00</span>
```

Comment: you aren't calling `clearInterval`

Comment: the reset part is here :  if (--timer < 0) { timer = duration; }.

Comment: `const interval = setInterval(....` and `if (--timer < 0) { window.clearInterval(interval) }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the interval when it reaches 0 instead of resetting to the duration.

Note: Your function seem to lag a bit at the first iteration, that is because the first calculation is the same as the value in the html. If that is not intentional you could fix that be decrementing the timer value by 1 before the interval logic.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalID)
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(5, display);
};
```

```html
<span id="time">0:05</span>
```